# How can I set expandtab but only for git commit messages?

Tags: vimrc, tab-characters

Most of the time I'd like `noexpandtab` on because our corporate formatting uses tabs instead of spaces, so in my `.vimrc` I have this:

```
" Set tab width stuff
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=0 noexpandtab shiftwidth=4
```

What is annoying though is when I am writing my git commit messages and tabs come in, I'd like those to be spaces. I know I could just do `:set expandtab` when I'm writing a commit message but it seems annoying to do every time. Surely there is a better way?

For what it's worth I'm running vim through git bash in Git for Windows.

Comment: What's the value of `:set ft?` when you write a commit message? If it's git related, you can then write a specific `autocmd FileType` event that sets your `expandtab` option.

Comment: @VanLaser `:set ft` gives `filetype=gitcommit`, I'll look into `autocmd`, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Put `set expandtab` in a file `after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First possibility**

Add the following line to your .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType gitcommit setlocal expandtab
```

**Second possibility**

Create a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`

and in there put:

```
:setlocal expandtab
```

See the faq:

- [How do I configure Vim to automatically set the 'textwidth' option to a particular value when I edit mails](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-14.11)
- [How do I extend an existing filetype plugin?](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.3)
- [How do I set different options for different types of files?](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.1)